# Embed works in Firefox and Safari, but not in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer-8

I have a flash-based ad that displays/hides based on some javascript. It works in Firefox, Safari, Chrome ... but not in Internet Explorer 8. This is for donations to a non-profit during the holiday season, so any help would be wonderful.

See the [test site](http://demo-studio360.wnyc.net/).

Thank you!
Peter

> ```
>   <div class="grid_12 alpha omega">
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>       GA_googleFillSlot("360_dropdown");
>     </script><script src="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?correlator=1323096793738&amp;output=json_html&amp;callback=GA_googleSetAdContentsBySlotForSync&amp;impl=s&amp;client=ca-pub-1030295571732009&amp;slotname=360_dropdown&amp;page_slots=360_dropdown&amp;cookie_enabled=1&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fdemo-studio360.wnyc.net%2F&amp;lmt=1323096764&amp;dt=1323096793743&amp;biw=1201&amp;bih=961&amp;adk=203353989&amp;ifi=1&amp;u_tz=-360&amp;u_his=2&amp;u_java=true&amp;u_h=1200&amp;u_w=1920&amp;u_ah=1174&amp;u_aw=1920&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_nplug=10&amp;u_nmime=85&amp;flash=11.0.1&amp;gads=v2&amp;ga_vid=901695308.1323096794&amp;ga_sid=1323096794&amp;ga_hid=1643565815"></script><div id="google_ads_div_360_dropdown_ad_container"><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pri.org/developer/js/flash_v3005.js"></script>
> ```
>
> var pop_suppress = "true";
>
> ```
>         function show_div(div_id) {
>
>             // hide all the divs
>
>             document.getElementById('pencil').style.display = 'none';
>
>             document.getElementById('expand').style.display = 'none';
>
>             document.getElementById('intro583325').style.display = 'none';
>
>             // show the requested div
>
>             document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = 'block';
>
>         }
> ```
>
> ```
>         function auto_show_div(div_id) {
>
>             // hide all the divs
>
>             document.getElementById('pencil').style.display = 'none';
>
>             document.getElementById('expand').style.display = 'none';
>
>             document.getElementById('intro583325').style.display = 'none';
>
>             // show the requested div
>
>             document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = 'block';
>
>         }
> ```
>
> ```
> <div style="position: absolute; top: 1px; right: 1px;">
>
>     <a href="" onclick="show_div('expand'); return false;" style="outline: none;"><img src="http://www.pri.org/developer/images/adtop_expand.png" alt="Expand Ad" border="0" height="23" width="23"></a>
>
> </div>
> ```
>
> //  `var SOB=new flashObj();
>
>   var enc_goto = escape("http://secure.publicbroadcasting.net/pri/banner/pledge.pledgemain");
>
>   var enc_goto2 = escape("");
>
>   SOB.ID = "reexpand_ad";
>
>   SOB.flashFile = "http://media.wnyc.org/media/resources/2011/Nov/30/360pushdown.swf";
>
>   SOB.DenyIEdl = "TRUE";
>
>   SOB.wmode = "opaque";
>
>   SOB.width = "960";
>
>   SOB.height = "230";
>
>   SOB.FlashVer = 9;
>
>   SOB.cabVersion = "9,0,0,0";
>
>   SOB.altTxt = '<a href="http://www.pri.org/give-pri.html" target="_new">Give to PRI</a>';
>
>   SOB.render(true);`
>
>   
>     //]]>
>
> ```
>     <a href="" onclick="show_div('pencil'); return false;" style="outline: none;"><img src="http://www.pri.org/developer/images/adtop_collapse.png" alt="Contract Ad" border="0" height="23" width="23"></a>
>
> </div>
> ```
>
> ```
> //<! [CDATA[
>
>     var SOB=new flashObj();
>
>     var enc_goto = escape("http://secure.publicbroadcasting.net/pri/banner/pledge.pledgemain");
>
>     var enc_goto2 = escape("");
>
>
>
>     SOB.ID = "intro_ad";
>
>     SOB.flashFile = "http://media.wnyc.org/media/resources/2011/Nov/30/360pushdown.swf";
>
>     SOB.DenyIEdl = "TRUE";
>
>     SOB.wmode = "opaque";
>
>     SOB.width = "960";
>
>     SOB.height = "230";
>
>     SOB.FlashVer = 9;
>
>     SOB.cabVersion = "9,0,0,0";
>
>     //SOB.altTxt = '<a href="http://www.pri.org/give-pri.html" target="_new">Give to PRI</a>';
>
>     SOB.render(true);
>
> //]]>
>
> </script><embed src="http://media.wnyc.org/media/resources/2011/Nov/30/360pushdown.swf" swliveconnect="FALSE" quality="best" scale="exactfit" flashvars="null" wmode="opaque" id="intro_ad" name="flash2" menu="false" devicefont="false" salign="lt" allowscriptaccess="Always" allownetworking="All" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" height="230" width="960">
>
> <div style="position: absolute; top: 1px; right: 1px;">
>
>     <a href="" onclick="show_div('pencil'); return false;" style="outline: none;"><img src="http://www.pri.org/developer/images/adtop_collapse.png" alt="Contract Ad" border="0" height="23" width="23"></a>
>
> </div>
> ```
>
> //["ID of content to frequency cap", "Display frequency interval (full hours only)"]
>   
>   var capcontent=new Array()
>   
>   capcontent[0]=["intro583325", "24 hr"]
>   
>   
>   
>   function get_cookie(Name) {
>   
>     var search = Name + "="
>   
>     var returnvalue = "";
>   
>     if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
>
> ```
> offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
>
> if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists
>
>   offset += search.length
>
>   end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
>
>   if (end == -1)
>
>      end = document.cookie.length;
>
>   returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
>
>   }
> ```
>
> }
>   
>     return returnvalue;
>   
>   }
>   
>   
>   
>   function resetcookie(id){
>   
>   var expireDate = new Date()
>   
>   expireDate.setHours(expireDate.getHours()-10)
>   
>   document.cookie = id+"=;path=/;expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString()
>   
>   }
>   
>   
>   
>   function showorhide(caparray){
>   
>   if (get_cookie(caparray[0])!=''){
>   
>   document.write("#"+caparray[0]+"{display: none;}\n")//CSS TO HIDE CONTENT BTW FREQUENCY
>   
>   document.getElementById('pencil').style.display = 'block';
>   
>   }else{
>   
>   var t=setTimeout("auto_show_div('pencil')",14000);
>   
>   var expireDate = new Date()
>   
>   expireDate.setHours(expireDate.getHours()+parseInt(caparray[1]))
>   
>   document.cookie = caparray[0]+"="+parseInt(caparray[1])+";path=/;expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString()
>   
>   }
>   
>   }
>   
>   
>   
>   document.write('\n')
>   
>   
>   
>   for (i=0; i')
>
> ```
>   </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that Internet Explorer doesn't support the embed tag.  I would suggest using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) framework to load Flash content.